# Magento 2 - How can i move the category page title to the top of the catalog nav block on left?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, layered-navigation

I need to add the page title on the top of sidebar navigation block,
i tired with the following but still it renders below the layered navigation.

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="sidebar.main" before="-" />
```

Comment: Can you update with screenshot and also your code?

Comment: <move element="page.main.title" destination="sidebar.main" before="-" />

Comment: Can you share any screenshot where you want to show the title?

Comment: In the top most portion of the category left navigation block

Comment: Is you code move the block to left?

Comment: I need the category header title to be placed inside the left filter navigation block...when i used above lines it gets placed in same block but at the bottom ,i need it to be placed at the top of the block

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code:

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="sidebar.main" before="catalog.leftnav" />
```

If it doesn't work then you need to change the order of **catalog.leftnav**.

Comment: Change the order means?where we can edit it?

Comment: got it..added.it worksI changed the  ordering of the catalog.leftnav after my logic again

Comment: Tick the green mark if it works for you.

Comment: For me work only when I use both: <move element="page.main.title" destination="sidebar.main" before="catalog.leftnav"/>
        <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="page.main.title"/>

Answer (score 0):

It works only if you do :

```
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="sidebar.main" before="catalog.leftnav"/>
        <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="page.main.title"/>
```